# Software to make each sound file in a directory louder?

Tags: audio

I have some sound files in a directory (e.g. MP3-files). Does there exist a tool to make each of them louder? E.g. making each 3 dB louder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/). It can make a single file louder, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a "volume=3dB" output.mp3
```

You could then use a Windows CMD loop to apply this to all files

```
MD output
FOR %M IN (*.mp3) DO ffmpeg -i "%M" -filter:a "volume=3dB" "output\%M"
```

Advantage:

- it's [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) and [free](/questions/tagged/free)

Disadvantage:

- It's a console application, not a fancy user interface
- FFMPEG will not manipulate files in-place. But, maybe it's good to have the original file still available, so you can listen to some result.

Answer (score 0):

There are many online and offline tools that can be used to make the audio louder. One of them is Format Factory.

Format Factor provides audio and video converter, clipper, joiner, spliter, mixer, crop and delogo.It also includes video players, screen recorder and video downloader.

Advantages

- Format factory is free
- The app has an easy and clean user interface
- It supports a wider range of media files

Disadvantaged

- The app is Windows only